# How to find similarity between two list of strings using doc2vec?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, doc2vec

I have a list of strings like below. I would like to see similarity between list1 and list2 using Doc2Vec.

```
list1 = [['i','love','machine','learning','its','awesome'],['i', 'love', 'coding', 'in', 'python'],['i', 'love', 'building', 'chatbots']]
list2 = ['i', 'love', 'chatbots']
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `Doc2Vec` implementation in the `gensim` library, there are intro notebooks that cover this. See for example the file `doc2vec-lee.ipynb`, which is inside the `gensim` `docs/notebooks` directory (where you can and sould run it locally), or viewable online at:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb

Note that:

- you'll need a model trained on far more data - ideally tens-of-thousands or more texts, each text being at least a sentence
- if the two texts you want to compare were part of your training set, you can retrieve the learned doc-vectors from the model
- if the two texts you want to compare are not part of the training set, you can infer doc-vectors for them, using the model, as is shown in that notebook